# How to configure Redis caching in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, redis

How can I configure Redis caching with Spring Boot. From what I have heard, it's just some changes in the `application.properties` file, but don't know exactly what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `Redis` caching in your Spring boot application all you need to do is set these in your `application.properties` file

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.redis.host=localhost //add host name here
spring.redis.port=6379
```

Add this dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, you have to use the `@EnableCaching` on your main application class and use the `@Cacheable` annotation on the methods to use the Cache. That is all is needed to use `redis` in a Spring boot application. You can use it in any class by autowiring the CacheManager in this case RedisCacheManager.

```
@Autowired
RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mention all the required properties that is hostname, port etc. in the application.properties file and then read from it.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class SpringSessionRedisConfiguration {

@Value("${redis.hostname}")
private String redisHostName;

@Value("${redis.port}")
private int redisPort;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHostName(redisHostName);
    factory.setPort(redisPort);
    factory.setUsePool(true);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
    return redisCacheManager;
}
```

}

Comment: I think, this is not the Spring Boot way. In Spring Boot we don't need to create all these cache manager and stuffs (from what I have read and heard)

Comment: I guess this gives you more flexibility in configuration.

Comment: that is true, but I need the Spring Boot way

Comment: did you find the spring boot way?