# Spring's @Cacheable unable to cache data - Redis implementation

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I am trying to use spring cache abstraction with Redis cache. I am unable to see the values in cache. Please help me if I am missing something in config :

As I am making the call multiple times actual fetch is happening. I tried connecting to same redis host port, I cant find there any keys as well.

PFB the implementation details.

CacheUtils.java :

```
@Slf4j
public class CacheUtils {

    private final CustomerManagementClient customerManagementClient;

    @Autowired
    public CacheUtils(CustomerManagementClient customerManagementClient) {
        this.customerManagementClient = customerManagementClient;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "merchant-details", key = "#merchantEntityId")
    public MerchantDetails getOrFetchMerchantDetails(OrderItemStatusChangeEvent event, MerchantType merchantType, String merchantEntityId) {

        if (BUYER == merchantType) {
            log.info("test - get buyer details");
            CustomerDetails customerDetails = 
            customerManagementClient.getData(merchantEntityId);
            String businessId = customerDetails.getBusinessId();
            String phoneNumber = customerDetails.getPhoneNumber();

            return MerchantDetails
                    .builder()
                    .merchantEntityId(merchantEntityId)
                    .businessId(businessId)
                    .businessName(customerDetails.getBusinessName())
                    .merchantType(merchantType)
                    .contactNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .build();

        } 
        throw new InvalidInputException();
    }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MainClass implements LogisticsPlanningService {

  
    private final CacheUtils cacheUtils;

    @Autowired
    public LogisticsPlanningServiceImpl(CacheUtils cacheUtils) {
        this.cacheUtils = cacheUtils;
    }

    private Set<LogisticsPlanningRequest> testMethod(Event event) {

        MerchantDetails senderDetails = cacheUtils.getOrFetchMerchantDetails(event, SELLER, orderItem.getSellerId());
        MerchantDetails receiverDetails = cacheUtils.getOrFetchMerchantDetails(event, BUYER, orderItem.getBuyerId());
        
    }
}
```

RedisConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfiguration {

    private String hostName;
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    MarketPlaceServiceProperties properties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        hostName = properties.getRedisHostName();
        port = Integer.parseInt(properties.getRedisPort());
    }

    @Bean
    protected JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(hostName, port);
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    public RedisCacheConfiguration getTestCacheConfig() {
        RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();
        cacheConfiguration.prefixCacheNameWith("marketplace");
        cacheConfiguration.disableCachingNullValues();
        return cacheConfiguration;
    }


//    @Bean
//    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
//        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
//        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
//        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Object.class));
//        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
//        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
//        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
//        return redisTemplate;
//    }
}
```

service.properties :

```
redisHostName: redis.domain.prod.xyz.com
redisPort: 5400
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Redis caching in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111815/how-to-configure-redis-caching-in-spring-boot)

Comment: tried this but it did not help

Comment: In my case I checked the wrong db, db id was 1 in my code but I checked db0 on redisinsight, you may like to check.